# Gallio Icarus: Sort tests in Test Explorer according to Test.Order or DependsOn attributes

Tags: unit-testing, mbunit, gallio

Gallio + MBUNIT are used. I have rather big test fixtures, which consist from 30-40 test. Test run in the the order defined using [Test(Order=)] attribute, also [DependsOn()] is used to don't run next test if previous failed. If open the DLL in the Gallio Icarus runner, then the tests are ordered NOT in the order they will actually run. I also tried change values in the combobox on the TestExplorer toolbar, but didn't find any applicable category.

Is there any way to sort tests inside Gallio Icarus according to the Test.Order attribute?

Some plugins? Or maybe it's easy to implement own plugin, which does the same?
My manager doesn't like to see the 40 tests unsorted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry. Googled an existing gallio icarus ticket. Currently it is not possible..
http://code.google.com/p/mb-unit/issues/detail?id=916#makechanges